# Sbt to download list of jars specified

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a list of JARs and I want to download the JARs via SBT into destination directory specified. Is there a way/command to do this?

What I am trying is to have a list of jars in classpath for an external system like spark.
By default spark adds some jars to classpath and 
I also have some jars that my app depends on in addition to spark classpath jars.

I don't want to build a fat jar. 
And I need to package the dependent jars along with my jar in a tar ball.

My build.sbt

```
name := "app-jar"

scalaVersion := "2.10.5"

dependencyOverrides += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % scalaVersion.value

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation")

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.4.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.4.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka" % "1.4.1"


// I want these jars from here
libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "1.4.0-M3"

libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector-java" % "1.4.0-M3"

libraryDependencies += "com.google.protobuf" % "protobuf-java" % "2.6.1"
...

// To here in my tar ball
```

So far I have achieved this using a shell script.

I want to know if there is a way to do the same with sbt .

Comment: Please add to question content of your `build.sbt` file.

Comment: what does "list of JARs" mean? library which can download from maven, or something you have in your server. please give as an example of it.

Comment: I have added my build.sbt and explained my question.

Answer (score 0):

Add [sbt-pack](https://github.com/xerial/sbt-pack) to your `project/plugins.sbt` (or create it):

```
addSbtPlugin("org.xerial.sbt" % "sbt-pack" % "0.7.9")
```

Add `packAutoSettings` to your `build.sbt` and then run:

```
sbt pack
```

In `target/pack/lib` you will find all jars (with dependencies).

**Update**

Add new task to sbt:

```scala
val libraries = Seq(
 "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "1.4.0-M3",
 "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector-java" % "1.4.0-M3",
 "com.google.protobuf" % "protobuf-java" % "2.6.1"
)

libraryDependencies ++=  libraries


lazy val removeNotNeeded = taskKey[Unit]("Remove not needed jars")


removeNotNeeded := {
    val fileSet = libraries.map(l => s"${l.name}-${l.revision}.jar").toSet
    println(s"$fileSet")

    val ver = scalaVersion.value.split("\\.").take(2).mkString(".")
    println(s"$ver")    

    file("target/pack/lib").listFiles.foreach{
    file =>
    val without = file.getName.replace(s"_$ver","")
    println(s"$without")
    if(!fileSet.contains(without)){
               println(s"${file.getName} removed")
        sbt.IO.delete(file) 
    }
    }
}
```

After calling `sbt pack` call `sbt removeNotNeeded`. You will received only needed jar files.

Comment: This is not what I want .  I need only few jars that I have specified in my build.sbt . The above will download all jars.

Comment: I think the solution is to run `sbt-pack`. It downloads all jar files to `target/pack/lib`. Then copy only mentioned files (or delete other) from this directory (use `new java.io,File("target/pack/lib").listFiles.filter` then sbt.IO.copy - http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.7/api/index.html#sbt.IO$).